# PHP: How to convert this string to another datetime format?

Tags: php, date-format

I have this datetime as string: *Thu, 16 Aug 2012 13:17:25 +0200*

I want to reformat it so it becomes Donnerstag, 16.08.2012 13:17:25 (German format). I tried the format function, but it threw an error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date('format', strtotime('Thu, 16 Aug 2012 13:17:25 +0200'));
```

OR

```
$date = new DateTime('Thu, 16 Aug 2012 13:17:25 +0200');
$date->format('formatstring');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the usage of the setlocale function, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php for details.

You need to have the locales installed, if this code doesn't not work(eg, everything is the same) you are missing them on your system and need to sort that out first:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
echo strftime("%c") . PHP_EOL;
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'be_NL');
echo strftime("%c") . PHP_EOL;
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
echo strftime("%c") . PHP_EOL;
```

strftime is the function that supports the use of locale, e.g is responsible for outputting in the language of choice.  Some date related functions do not support this, however when you check those on php.net locale support will be mentioned if applicable.